# Ker and eigenvalues of projection endomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a vector space such that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ where every vector $\vec{x}$ can be written in a unique way as $\vec{x}=\vec{x_1}+\vec{x_2}$ where $\vec{x_1} \in W_1$ and $\vec{x_2} \in W_2$

Then consider the endomorphism $p:V\rightarrow V$ such that $p(\vec{x})=\vec{x_1}$

Can I say that $ker(p)=W_2$ even if it is not necessarily true that $W_2=W_1^{\perp}$?

Is this a consequence of the fact that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$?

This is equivalent to state that $W_2$ is the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $0$. And of course the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $1$ is $W_1$. But how can I be sure that there are no other eigenspaces?

Thanks in advice for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for if $v$ is in $W_2$, then the $x_1, x_2$ decomposition of $v$ is 
$$v = 0 + v,$$ and hence $T(v) = 0$

That shows that $W_2$ is a subspace of $Ker(T)$. You can work out the other direction yourself, I bet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because any vector of the form $x=x_2+0$ will be sent to $0$.